# Validation for TextBox For a User Form

Tags: asp.net, validation

In my User Registration Form,  I want my user address text box to accpet alphanumeric as well as special character but should not contain only numeric or special character.

I am currently using regular expression validator ,what regular expression i can use.

Or Is there any different solution for that.

Regards

Comment: Could you add specified samples of what patterns/values are allowed and what not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.. I have used it at one place, and works pretty well.. just provide your acceptable characters and you are good to go

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You mean from your question that a string of alphabets is a must right ?

Comment: you may browse some samples here: http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?categoryId=7&cattabindex=6